# When and how to use the Central Limit Theorem?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, descriptive-statistics

I'm currently trying to solve an exercise in statistics.

I have got many hundred observations for some measured fluctations.

In a normal Q-Q plot, I have plotted all the observations and a line has been drawed. This is all done by software.

As I can see, the plotted observations do not really differ from a straight line, maybe only a little bit at the beginning of the line and at the end of line. Therefore, as I understand, I can assume that the data (the observations) follow a normal distribution.

However, in the exercise, I'm told to make use of the central limit theorem. But as I understand, this theorem should only be used if I can't assume a normal distribution (if the plotted observations differed from a straight line).

Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: To me it's more important to know when to NOT use it, as statisticians use it for most everything, even if not applicable ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple words, the Central Limit Theorem says that the sum of a *sufficiently large* number of weakly dependent quantities has a distribution close to normal, *regardless of their initial distribution*.

So

> But as I understand, this theorem should only be used if I can't
>   assume a normal distribution (if the plotted observations differed
>   from a straight line).

you don't need any assumptions on prior distributions, and it is really the main key point of CLT.

**UPDATE** (Thanks to comment by Karl): You don't need any special assumptions on prior distribution while it has well-defined finite mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. There exist examples of such distributions which don't satisfy this requirement.

Comment: @Karl, yes, you are right. It must has well-defined and finite mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Thanks, I'm going to edit my answer. By the way, the answer to OP's question is still "no, it isn't necessary to assume normal distribution to prior".

Comment: I agree with you. I don't see how the CLT is immediately relevant to QQ plots as the OP question seems to be hinting at.